# Jquery / HTML5 / Ajax upload progress bar?

Tags: java, jquery, upload

I'm working on a simple S3 uploader, got it to perform and do what I need to do; however, I was wondering if there was an easy to create an upload progress bar?

At the bottom of the browser, there is a browser message that says "Uploading" - is there any articles anyone knows about that piggy-backs off of this to display a loading bar?

Ideally, that variable will be passed to a jquery function that renders the percentage in the bootstrap progressbar (which accepts integers).

The goal here is to be more aesthetically pleasing, not necessarily 100% accurate.

[image: This is the upload percent from the browser]

Answer (score 6):

if you're using a XMLHttpRequest object, you can use onprogress event and the lenghtcomputable attr of the event
.You should only do this if your XMLHttpRequest supports  progress
(test = "upload" in new XMLHttpRequest)

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'post/picture');
xhr.onload = function() {
   progress.value = progress.innerHTML = 100;
};


xhr.upload.onprogress = function (event) {
    if (event.lengthComputable) {
        var complete = (event.loaded / event.total * 100 | 0);
        progress.value = progress.innerHTML = complete;
    }
}

xhr.send(formData);
```

Comment: This is indeed the proper way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the progress bar of jquery UI?

[Main of jQuery Progress Bar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/)

Comment: what he wants to know , is how the get the status of the upload process