# How to show file uploading progress bar using html form and php code

Tags: php, html, file, progress-bar, uploading

I am using an HTML form to upload files 
and PHP code to save the form file in the directory 
and its working fine

But I need to show the progress bar using the browser status bar(shown in image file) or something similar 
but now with the jquery etc.

let me know if there is any possible solution with pure HTML and PHP

don't mark my question down I have searched it everywhere

Thanks in advance

---

[image: Browser default uploading progress bar]

Comment: Why don't you want to use jQuery? Yes, it might add much unused code to your project, but you gain much more than writing it on your own and fiddle around with browser inconsistencies

Comment: i already implement all my logic using PHP but if i will add jquery then I need a lot of more and extra code

Comment: For using jQuery, you don't need a single line of PHP. But okay - have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/13766628

Comment: i will test it thank s